# Windows Exchange Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have changed the password for the 1st time in 7 years on our exchange server. I hit control/alt/del and changed the password. I also went into the backup exec program and changed the password. After I rebooted the server (after doing MS update) now backup exec will not start up. 
I have tried stopping all the services, change the server password again, restart the services and it still will not start up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any messages in the event log?

Answer (score 3):

Go to the Services control panel/MMC.  Select Properties for one of the Backup Exec services, on the Logon tab update the password with the new info, Apply, restart the Service.
Repeat for each BE service, reboot if needed.
This can happen to other services, use the Log on As column to see if anything else is running  under the same account.

Comment: What I did was change the administrator password in our MS Server 2003 after it being hacked and spam was sent out from our server. Now that we no longer have the spam issue, I can not get our backup exec services to work and also having problems with one of the newer workstations not being able to connect to the server for Trend antivirus updates, so I now know this is a "services" issue.   Anyway... Do I need to go to every "service" on the server to update the password manually or is there someway to do so all at once?

Comment: Also is there any add'l issues I might have after changing all the "services" passwords and rebooting. It would be a complete nightmare if the server didn't come up after changing passwords since our email is on the server...

Comment: If you are concerned about an account lockout or incorrect password then add another account w/ a separate password & Domain Admin priviledges, logon 1x to confir prior to changing the administrator acct pswd.  Re. changing the service account pswd: as suggested above, use the "Log on As" column in Services to see which services are using the Administrator account.  Most services do not use this account, probably <10 will need to be changed.  Longer term, better to use a separate account for services rather than a single Administrator account for everything.